# problem in sending document when I click cancel

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a link in aspx page and when i click on it,it shows a popup: open,save,cancel

but when i click cancel on that aspx page no other link works on that page.

code so far:

```
protected void method1()
{
            byte[] byterendered = _Filename.OpenBinary();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.jpg");
            Response.CacheControl = "Public";
            Response.BinaryWrite(byterendered);
            Response.End();
}
```

aspx code

```
<asp:Linkbutton id="link1" runat="server" onClick="method1" Text="LinkA"/>
 <asp:Linkbutton id="link2" runat="server" onClick="method2" Text="LinkB" />
```

Comment: When do you call this code? Have you considered opening the file in a new window?

Comment: Can you post the ASPX code as well?

Comment: @Kobi: what do u mean by when you say opening the file in new window. Right now when i open the file it shows popup so u mean instead of that it should have new window?

@Prustswonder: I have added aspx code above

Comment: I mean: instead of using the current `Response`, you can have a link that opens on a popup (`target='_new'`). After the file is downloaded the Response may have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to your question have indicated, the reason is because your Response is being ended after the file dialog shows up. Once the response ends, any other actions on your page will not be registered. I ran into this myself while implementing a download function for my SharePoint app.

Basically, what you want to do is have your link buttons perform a window open script, instead of directly running the file transfer, like the following.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="link1" runat="server" onClick="window.open('TARGETURL'); return false;" Text="LinkA" />
```

Replace `TARGETURL` with an aspx page URL. Then, create a new ASPX page for the URL you specified. It will be pretty much empty, all you need are two lines.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="YOURFOURPARTASSEMBLYSTRINGHERE" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits"YOURNAMESPACE.DOWNLOADCODE" %>
```

Replace `YOURFOURPARTASSEMBLYSTRINGHERE` with, of course, the four-part assembly string for your code. `YOURNAMESPACE.DOWNLOADCODE` will be replaced with the namespace and class that you will create for the page. The class will need to inherit the base page type, I personally used LayoutsPageBase since that's a perfect thing to use in a SharePoint app. All this class needs is an OnLoad method like the following.

```
// Don't actually name your class DOWNLOADCODE.
public class DOWNLOADCODE : LayoutsPageBase
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] byterendered = _Filename.OpenBinary(); //More on this afterwards
        Response.Clear();    
        Response.ClearHeaders();    
        Response.ClearContent();    
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";    
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=abc.jpg");    
        Response.CacheControl = "Public";    
        Response.BinaryWrite(byterendered);    
        Response.End(); 
    }
}
```

You will have to retrieve _Filename in this new page, of course. The best way to do this is to take whatever parameters you use to determine _Filename in the first place, and pass it as part of the URL query string.

Using this, clicking the link button will open a new window, but since all this page does it have a file response, it will just open the file dialog and be done with it. Meanwhile, your original aspx page will not have ended its response, so it can continue whatever function you need it to.